# What the main difference between Sql Server Enterprise Manager and Sql Server Enterprise Edition?

Tags: sql-server

I think its a strange question but my problem now that I ordered from my organization to buy a license for SQL Server Enterprise edition, but after they made order I found that I only need SQL Server Enterprise Manager just to manage my DB during developing a  asp.net website.

So can I ask the organization to return SQL Server Enterprise Edition back or is it impossible? And do I need to buy SQL Server Enterprise manager or there is a free version online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise Manager is the SQL Server 2000 GUI client tool. No server side components. No database engine, no analysis services, no reporting services.

Enterprise Edition refers to the server side components feature level (has more than Standard, Workgroup). This is separate to the the GUI/client components.

Enterprise Manager has been replaced by "SQL Server Management Studio" ("SSMS") since SQL Server 2005. This can manage all editions

Comment: so that means if i am just developing a website with database i will use Sql server management only not need for SQL server Enterprise right?

Comment: And where will your database run?

Comment: look i am developing i asp.net web site then they have already a server for them but while developing do i need the sql server Enterprise Edition?

Comment: excuse me  "both for what"? and really i appreciate your help :) you clarified a lot of things for me :)

Comment: Will you develop on their server? Or on your own?

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaanks a lot MR gbn you answered all my questions perfectly i appreciate your help :)